# Como sustituir valores en array de php

Tags: php, php7, php5

Tengo un sitio de streaming.

Necesito saber como puedo sustituir palabras en una respuesta de php con otra ya establecida.

Me explico:
Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
$url= 'http://example.com/hls/test.m3u8';
readfile("$url");

$regex= 'testB';
$t= str_replace ('http://example.com/hls/', $regex, $url);
echo $t
```

Y la respuesta a su ejecución es esta:

```
#EXTM3U 
#EXT-X-VERSION:3 
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:16288 
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:6 
#EXTINF:6.006, 
test-16288.ts 
#EXTINF:6.006, 
test-16289.ts 
#EXTINF:6.006, 
test-16290.ts 
#EXTINF:6.006, 
test-16291.ts 
#EXTINF:6.006, 
test-16292.ts 
#EXTINF:6.006, 
test-16293.ts 
http://example.com/hls/test.m3u8
```

Ahora, lo que quiero lograr es que test- en la respuesta sea sustituida por http://example.com/hls/testB, y ya que es hls no resulte afectada la reproducción, ya que no se reproduce si no se sustituye, ya que he leido que no se reproduce porque el navegador cree que yo tengo el contenido, pero es un link externo; y que no salga la última línea de abajo.

He intentado con muchos codigos que encontré en muchos otros artículos en Google y hasta he probado con algo llamado 'proxy php' y aunque funciona, todos los codigos que he probado me llevan al mismo resultado, y mi objetivo es que se reproduzca desde un php ya que quiero proteger el link de los sniffer, ocultandolo en mi dominio.

La verdad no se mucho de php, agradecería toda la ayuda posible.

Comment: Por lo que entiendo de tu pregunta, creo que necesitas usar AJAX. PHP se va a interpretar, y luego te va a llegar una página con el enlace cambiado. Pero recargando toda la página...

Comment: Me puedes dar un ejemplo de como haria eso? Sé muy poco de ajax, no veo como hacerlo.